# How to get element by id and class attributes?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an element with class value as "classA" and id value as "id1". I know how I can get elements using class or id, but there are many elements with class value "classA" and there many elements with id value "id1". Therefore I need to get element using class and id. Please, tell me, how can I do it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The `id` value must be unique by HTML specifications. Violating this causes various problems, e.g. a selector might not match *any* of the elements.

So you simply need to change `id` values so that they are unique withing the document.

Use the W3C Markup Validator, since it detects multiply-defined `id` values, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

in jQuery:

```
$("div#IDvalue.classname")
```

and note that in fact `ID`s must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

`Id` should be always unique according to the standards. Do not duplicate the id.
Classes can be duplicated across mutilple `HTML` elements.

Answer (score 0):

ids need to be explicitly diffrent ..

```
getElementById('#id').value
```

For class use something like this

```
getElementsByClassName("classname")[0].value 
getElementsByClassName("classname")[1].value
```

Comment: [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) (plural)